# Animation is not happening in python

Tags: python

I m trying to make an animation plot in python using matplotlib.animation and the package is present. But when I execute the program it is not showing any error but also no animation is there.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

n=100
x= np.random.randn(n)
def update(curr):
if curr == n:
    a.event_source.stop()
    plt.cla()
    bins = np.arrange(-4,4,0.5)
    plt.hist(x[:curr],bins=bins)
    plt.axis([-4,4,0,30])
    plt.gca().set_title('Sampling the normal distribution')
    plt.gca().set_xlabel('Value')
    plt.gca().set_ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.annotate('n={}'.format(curr),[3,27])


    fig = plt.figure() 
    a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,interval =100)
```

Looking forward to a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Please paste the traceback

Comment: Please fix your code. Indentation, therefore `a` is not defined, `np.arange`.